# Laravel route, i get File not found

Tags: laravel

after defining simple route in `api.php`, `route:list` return this output in console:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI          | Name | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /            |      | Closure                                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/v1/login |      | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ApiController@login | api        |
+--------+----------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

now i exept when i try to opening this url as `www.www.com/api/v1/login`, that work fine for me, but i get this message in browser

```
File not found.
```

composer output:

```
# composer dump-autoload
Generating optimized autoload files> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
Generated optimized autoload files containing 5074 classes
```

`api.php` content:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', 'Api\v1\ApiController@login');
});
```

Comment: `File not found.` it seems other problem not `router`

Comment: If you get this in the browser console, then the message is probably being printed from the frontend, not the backend. Check your `console.log`s

Comment: Should be nginx error, not related to laravel

Comment: do all routes besides the root route of your site return this error? if so this is a misconfiguration of your webserver

Comment: @lagbox i think problem is on our server, i'm not sure, all of things seems are correct

Comment: right, if that is the webserver giving you a file not found error then potentially 'pretty urls' isn't configured properly ... you don't have an 'api' folder in 'public' do you?

Comment: @lagbox no i don't have

Answer (score 0):

For the list of implicit middlewares/middleware group applied to routes in **api.php/web.php** check **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

Check the "api" middleware group in **app/Http/kernel.php**.Other middlewares applied should be in **app/Http/Middleware/**

Answer (score -3):

Do you have a `.ENV` file in your `root` directory?
Or is it still `.ENV.EXAMPLE` ?

Comment: also its `.env` not `.ENV`

Comment: Fully agree. Sorry guys. This should have been a comment.